# My Amelanistic Corn Snake is turning yellow?

Tags: health, diseases, snakes, anatomy

[image]

This is my corn snake, Pyro, I just got him out today to feed him. Last week when I got him out, I didn't notice any different colors, but he had a yellow tint around his face/upper body. His temperature usually varies around 80-87 degrees Fahrenheit (27-31 degrees Celsius), sometimes getting to 90 degrees Fahrenheit (32 degrees Celsius). His humidity is around 40-60 %, sometimes getting up to 70 %.

I'm really nervous about it, I'm not sure if I need to take him to a vet or not? I researched about it and some people said it's normal, and it happens usually after they shed, he shed around 2-3 weeks ago? He's around 5-6 months old.

I use aspen shavings in his tank, and feed him in a separate container.
I feed him frozen pinkies once every week.

Comment: Wwlcome to pets.SE! This is a good quality question. But if you are in concern of your pet's health, do not wait for the guesses of strangers from the internet. Visit or call a vet, to get an experienced advice in time.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing has changed, and he's still eating and acting normal, there's probably nothing to worry about. Snakes often change color as they age, some very dramatically (e.g. green tree pythons, cotton mouths, copper heads. [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZlPcvjE1eM) has a video going into some detail about corns specifically.). See if it's still there after his next shed. That's about all I can say without more info.

Although you say "his temperature usually varies around 80-87 degrees Fahrenheit", I assume you mean his hot spot, and not the whole enclosure? He definitely should be able to get to cooler areas for thermoregulation.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some kind of source for your statement about color changing? This would make this answer more valuable for later users with the same question

Comment: I added some examples of specific snakes that exhibit this trait, that work? Or you mean like a link to a source saying that this occurs?

Comment: This is great, but a link would be perfect ;)

Comment: Thank you, I just fed him yesterday, he ate quickly but I think thats because his last feed was a little small. He's been getting out and about like normal, I'll keep an eye on him. thank you

Comment: oh , forgot to say, yes thats his hot spot

Answer (score 0):

The photo is extremely useful in this case, because other people may not notice or understand what it means when you say he's 5-6 months old. The picture makes it clear that this is a juvenile snake.

Nearly all of the many, many variations of Rat/Corn snake go through some changes in coloration as they mature. ***This is perfectly normal, and nothing to worry about.*** Some are fairly dramatic changes, such as baby Black Rat snakes that start out looking like black-and-white versions of your Corn snake and end up solid black. The Corn snakes tend to be less dramatic about it, but they do still change.

This does happen with other species, as well, but Rat/Corn snakes are among the most popularly kept snakes, so it's good to spread that knowledge.